# Some problems on my web page on INTERNET EXPLORER and not on other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Can someone help me please?

Am working on this page:

http://www.lorealprofessionnel.co.uk/about-us/loreal-professionnel-portfolio

On INTERNET EXPLORER, why I can't see arrows to navigate through the carousel. It works on all others browsers

I have put :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE[all version here]" />
```

but nothing !

Comment: 123 errors for starters: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lorealprofessionnel.co.uk%2Fabout-us%2Floreal-professionnel-portfolio&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: `.co.uk` but French spelling of "professional". Interesting!

Comment: `all version here` is probably not supposed to be verbatim.

Comment: all version means i put : ie7 or ie8 but nothin

Answer (score 0):

Actually those elements appear and disappear on Chrome too. When they're invisibile it seems something has given them explicit positions which are fighting with the logic in the original CSS. I can't find where precisely quickly because the page loads over 20 JavaScript files. I have rarely seen so much code to do so little. Screams of corporate CMS. I'm not surprised debugging this is a nightmare.

Comment: entirely agree: the js developer is killing me.

Comment: The js files is carrousel3d.js, here     placeNav: function (){
        var coords = this.block.getCoordinates();
       
        //console.log(coords)
        $(this.options.prev).css({ left: (coords.left - $(this.options.prev).width()) + "px", top: (coords.top + (this.block.height() / 2)) + "px" });
        $(this.options.next).css({ right: coords.right - coords.width - 40+ "px", top: (coords.top + (this.block.height() / 2)) + "px" });
    },

Comment: OK I just put a breakpoint on that code; whenever it runs, the arrows disappear. Not sure what that code's role is in the whole thing; currently it just seems to break the layout.